# Typescript complains that type never is not assignable to type K in simple generic class

Tags: typescript

I have a generic Action-Class that takes T (an object of unknowns) and K (an array of parameters).
The action class should later be extended to construct other actions with different T and K. However, already the base Action class throws type errors I dont understand. The minimal example I could come up with was this:

```js
type ActionObjects = Record<string, unknown>
type ActionArgs = Array<any>
export class Action<T extends ActionObjects = ActionObjects, K extends Array<any> = ActionArgs> {
  static actionName: string
  objectStore: T = {} // ERROR 1
  args: K = [] // ERROR 2

  async redo (objects: T, ...args: K) {
    this.objectStore = objects
    this.args = args

    // other stuff
  }
}
```

[Typesript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYHkBGArCCDOUAvFAEp7IBOAJgDz7CWKoDmANFAK6oDWqyAd1QA+AFChIsBClQxKLQiTmUAhiForUIMRAAeYKsChwANivyF4SNLQAqUPcAipql6Wiy4CxKdYw48YHwOAGkHXScXS0pVdU1tHysZOQVhKABvUSgoBhUkOCgVd1QAORUAWwgALhzGZhYsqGQAhABlYCpqqHsSdIBfRpV5fBqwkgBtAF1RQfwQVALKCGpkKAAKZq8gmtsOADoDoYVRgEoMxuzgAAtEfD3NwPbOnweCC6hr272jxULhmey2QA9ECmtcIJRapwAGbQxoDPpAA)

The errors are:

1. Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
2. Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'K'.

What am I doing wrong?

If it's possible to automatically map the `actionName` to the required ActionObjects and ActionArgs that would be a bonus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first type `T`, it can be any type that has `string: unknown` properties. Therefore the empty object is not valid. What if T was the interface,

```
interface SomeType {
  prop1: unknown;
  prop2: unknown;
}
```

Clearly `{}` is not compatible with this type. don't get confused with generic types being able to be any type and being able to use any type in their place. The fact `T` can be so many types means that the way you can use it (and assign to it) is actually restricted.

In this case I would probably use the `T | null` type to represent your `objectStore` property and initialise it to null.

For the second error, it is very similar. `K` can be anything that extends an array - so it could be a really complicated object with lots of functionality that isn't in a simple array. That's why the empty array is not valid. This can be fixed by taking in the item type as `K` and then specifying `K[]` as below.

```
export class Action<T extends ActionObjects = ActionObjects, K = any> {
  static actionName: string

  objectStore: T | null = null;
  args: K[] = [];

  async redo (object: T, ...args: K[]) {
    this.objectStore = object
    this.args = args

    // other stuff
  }
}
```